# AutoMapper Many -> Many Relationships with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, mapping, automapper

I am using AutoMapper to map my Data. The Person Entity has a many TaskItems while each TaskItem has one person. My Day entity has Many TaskItems where each taskItem has only one day assigned. I tried to select the Day bellow. The TaskItem table is the joining table.

In my DaysApi controller I get this exception

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Error mapping types.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
```

```
CreateMap<Day, DaysDto>().ForMember(member => member.Week, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Week)).ForMember(member => member.People, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.People)).ForMember(member => member.TaskItems, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.TaskItems.Select(e => e.Day.DayId)
            .ToList()));
```

The exception is thrown in my GetDay(int id) method.

**My Dtos That are related**

```
public class DaysDto
    {
        public int DayId { get; set; }
        public string DayName { get; set; }

        public int WeekId { get; set; }
        public Week Week { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
        
        public ICollection<TaskItem> TaskItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
public int PersonId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool Monday { get; set; }
        public bool Tuesday { get; set; }
        public bool Wednesday { get; set; }
        public bool Thursday { get; set; }
        public bool Friday { get; set; }
        public bool Saturday { get; set; }
        public bool Sunday { get; set; }

        public ICollection<TaskItem> TaskItems { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 public class TaskItemDto
    {
        public int TaskItemId { get; set; }
        public string TaskName { get; set; }
        public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
        public TimeOfDay? TimeOfDay { get; set; }

        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public Person Person { get; set; }

        public int DayId { get; set; }
        public Day Day { get; set; }
    }
```

**Mapper Profiles**

```
public class DayProfile : Profile
    {
        public DayProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Day, DaysDto>().ForMember(member => member.Week, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Week)).ForMember(member => member.People, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.People)).ForMember(member => member.TaskItems, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.TaskItems.Select(e => e.Day.DayId)
            .ToList()));

            CreateMap<TaskItem, DaysDto>();

            CreateMap<DaysDto, Day>();
            

                
        }
    }
```

```
public class TaskItemProfile : Profile
    {
        public TaskItemProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<TaskItem, TaskItemDto>().ForMember(mem => mem.Day, o => o.MapFrom(e => e.Day))
                .ForMember(e => e.Person, o => o.MapFrom(e => e.Person));
            CreateMap<TaskItemDto, TaskItem>();
               

           
        }
    }
```

```
public class PersonProfile : Profile
    {
        public PersonProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Person, PersonDto>().ForMember(m => m.TaskItems, o => o.MapFrom(e => e.TaskItems.Select(e => e.Person.PersonId).ToList()));
            CreateMap<PersonDto, Person>();
        }
    }
```

**Where The Exception is thrown**

```
private readonly TaskDelegatingWebAppContext _context;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public DaysController(TaskDelegatingWebAppContext context, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }
        public IEnumerable<DaysDto> GetDays()
        {




            return _context.Day.Include(e => e.Week)
                .Include(e => e.TaskItems)
                .ToList()
                .Select(_mapper.Map<Day, DaysDto>);

        }

        // Get /api/Day/1
        [Route("/api/[controller]/{id}")]
        public DaysDto GetDay(int id)
        {
            var day = _context.Day.Include(e => e.Week).Include(e => e.TaskItems).Include(e => e.People).SingleOrDefault(c => c.DayId == id);

            if (day == null)
            {
                throw new HttpRequestException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound.ToString());
            }
            return _mapper.Map<Day, DaysDto>(day);

        }
```

I will Include a JSON of the data before the exception is thrown.

[Screenshot of Data spanning from Day, Person is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYLeP.png)

[Screenshot of Data spanning from TaskItem, Day is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwJQs.png)

I have tried selecting The person, and day from the taskItem collection in the Profiles and the api contoller, both did not work.

How do I select the Day and Person Navigation property using AutoMapper?

Comment: By "realted" do you mean related?

Comment: @PalleDue Yes!! sorry didn't notice the spelling error.